# Python discord bot commands aren't working

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Select,View

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):

    await ctx.send("hello")
bot.run("token here")
```

When I try to use the !test
nothing happens (no message or error)
what is the problem?
also installed library py-cord and discord.py

Comment: You should only install one of those libraries at a time, to avoid naming conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `Intents`. Create an `Intents` object, enable `message_content` (so your commands can be parsed) and it will work.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

You also need to enable the `message_content` in the Developer portal.

- The `message_content` intent is on the [first page of the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).
- [Discord intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.voice_states = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    if ctx.voice_client is not None:
        return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)

    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client is not None:
        return await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.command()
async def sound(ctx, sound: str):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        return await ctx.send('I am not connected to a voice channel.')

    if sound == 'default':
        await ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.5
        await ctx.send('Changed sound to default.')
    elif sound == 'high':
        await ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 2.0
        await ctx.send('Changed sound to high.')
    elif sound == 'low':
        await ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.2
        await ctx.send('Changed sound to low.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Invalid sound option.')

bot.run'YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).